# Why my Xcode 4.6 localize file only can choose English?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I can choose only Englist for localizing file in my Xcode 4.6.

Is this a bug of Xcode 4.6?

How to localize my file now?

Special thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try to add more localizations to the project or change default localization in info.plist (by adding CFBundleDevelopmentRegion key with value like en/nl/...)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Before localize a file you have to add the language to the application, see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You will have to add a localization to your project before you add a localization to a file in the project. See the image below:

[image: Adding localization to the project]

Answer (score 4):

You should add language in project->Info settings:
[image]